# Detect if method called via delegate discards argument

Tags: c#, parameters, c#-7.0

I'm making a command system for my console app. Some commands are used "as-is" (like "exitapp"), some require arguments (like "server start *ip* *port*"). Here's how I am doing it:

```
delegate void CommandHandlerMethod(params object[] args);
readonly Dictionary<string, CommandHandlerMethod> commands;
```

For methods which doesn't require arguments, i use discarding feature like this:

```
void ExitAppCommand(params object[] _) { ... }
void StartServerCommand(params object[] args)
{
   // ip = args[0];
   // port = args[1];
}
```

Then I just loop through dictionary, and I want to decide between two situations:
1. if command-handling method discard arguments then just call it
2. otherwise cut arguments from input string and pass it as args

So what is the option to detect argument discard?

UDP: This is "pseudo" of what I exactly want:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, CommandHandlerMethod> cmd in commands)
{
    (input.StartsWith(cmd.Key))
    {
        if (cmd.Value. /*is declared to discard arg */)
            cmd.Value();
        else
            // else cut args and pass them
            cmd.Value(input.Substring(cmd.Key.Length+1).Split(' '));
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not just always "cut arguments from input string and pass it as args"? That work will just be discarded if it's not wanted.

Comment: Yep I thought about that, but want to use this option if no better way is possible. I mean that I **anyway** need co compare input string length to command length (because if i substring more than intended, an exception will be raised).

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you're asking. You can add something like `if (args.count != <what was expected>) throw new Exception("....` to each command handler.

Comment: I mean if found command has this declaration: `void Command(params string[] _)` (ie. method is declared with argument but doesn't take it), then no substring would happen, and only if method accepts argument as usual, substring and parse them to this method.

Comment: updated a question to show what I exactly want in pseudo-code

Comment: The amount of reflection you would have to do to figure out "is declared to discard arg" would almost certainly be more expensive than just cutting and passing the args...

Answer (score 2):

The `_` in `void ExitAppCommand(params object[] _) { ... }` is not a [discard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/discards). `_` is a valid **C#** identifier.

In the following code, however, `_` is a discard:

```
public void N(int x)
{
    _ = x.ToString();
    _ = 2 + 3;
}
```

Chexk it out [here](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghgzgLgpgJwDQBMQGoA+ABAzAAmwCZ8BhAWACgBvK/ewg7AFnwFkAKABwgQjCj4A9sABWcAMYwA2gF18AfQCUdBrUoNN+AG698AD3wBeRQDoAMnAB2AcxgALANyr6AXxeNCrAHIcAllYwBioaah6aCsYGpgAqQgDKMAgBNhxKzqFailEk6Pi4GZrulK5AA=).

Comment: You're right, this is really works like this. But is it possible to ignore the argument then? To save the memory etc.

Comment: If you don't declare any parameters on the calling site, it will send `Array<T>.Empty()`. What memory are you worried about?

Comment: I mean that if user enters a command like "exitapp blablablaa bla bla bla", the handling method doesn't require any parameters, but will still get them because of that blabla being automatically cut and passed to params object[]. There comes useless data. But as canton7 mentioned above, detection of all this will utilize much reflection which aint performant too, so it seems to just better ignore that

Comment: The only way around it would be to declare the delegate with the right parameters and have something parsing them, like ASP.NET MVC/Web API does. It takes reflection for that and, probably, more memory.